# Derivative: matrix quadratic form when $\mathbf{B}$ is dependent on $\mathbf{m}$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I have the following equation:

$$
f = \mathbf{m^{T}Bm}
$$

where B is:

$$
\mathbf{B} = \frac{1}{3(m_{x}^{2} + m_{y}^{2})}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.5 & 1\\ 
0.5 & 1 & 0.5\\
1 & 1 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and m is:

$$
\mathbf{m} = \begin{pmatrix}
m_{x}\\ 
m_{y}\\ 
m_{z}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

also there is another equation:

$$
\mathbf{m} = a\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{y} + c\mathbf{z}
$$

**UPDATE:**

I extract the equation from a more complicated one but here

$m_x = a$, $m_y = b$ and $m_z = c$

My question is How can I calculate the derivative of f with respect to a ? Thanks very much.

Comment: Please clarify the equation $\mathbf{m} = ax + by + cz$ given that $\mathbf{m}$ is a vector.

Comment: @mlc I have updated the post. $\mathbf{m}$ is a vector.

Comment: The last equation is still confusing to me even after the edit. Do you mean is x supposed to represent the unit vector in the x direction, and likewise for y and z? That would make the most sense to me. But in this case $m=(a,b,c)$, and so the middle equation with $m_x$, etc is irrelevant.

Comment: I am still confused: $\mathbf{m} = ax+by+cz$ has a vector on the LHS; what is on the RHS?

Comment: @NickAlger I have updated the post. you are correct.

Comment: @mlc I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
P &= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix},\,\,
&Q = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cr\cr
m &= [\,a\,b\,c\,]^T \cr
M &= mm^T,\,\,\,
&f = \frac{P:M}{Q:M} \cr
}$$
where $\,:\,$ represents the inner/Frobenius product, i.e. $A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$

 
Find the differential of the function, then the gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= \frac{(Q:M)\,P:dM-(P:M)\,Q:dM}{(Q:M)^2} \cr
   &= \Bigg(\frac{(Q:M)\,P-(P:M)\,Q}{(Q:M)^2}\Bigg):dM \cr
   &= R:dM \cr
   &= R:(dm\,m^T+m\,dm^T) \cr
   &= R:dm\,m^T+R:m\,dm^T \cr
   &= R:dm\,m^T+R^T:dm\,m^T \cr
   &= (R+R^T)\,m:dm \cr
\cr
g=\frac{\partial f}{\partial m} &= (R+R^T)\,m \cr
\cr
}$$
The derivative wrt $a$ is the first component of the gradient
$$\eqalign{\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} &= g_x \cr\cr\cr}$$
**Update**

The gradient of the gradient can also be found. To make that calculation easier, let's use symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
P &= \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 4 & 3 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix},\,\,
&Q = \begin{bmatrix} 12 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 12 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} }$$ This won't change the function value because the skew parts are annihilated by the inner product with the symmetric matrix $M$. This change makes $R$ symmetric, too.

Let's also define some scalar coefficients to simplify the expression for $R$
$$\eqalign{
R &= \alpha P-\beta Q,\,\,\,&dR&= P\,d\alpha-Q\,d\beta \cr
\alpha&=(Q:M)^{-1},\,\,\,&d\alpha&=-\alpha^2(Q:dM)=-2\alpha^2\,m^TQ\,dm \cr
\beta &= \alpha^2(P:M) = \alpha f,\,\,\,&d\beta&=\alpha\,df + f\,d\alpha \cr
&\,&\,&= \alpha g^T\,dm - 2f\alpha^2\,m^TQ\,dm \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of $g$
$$\eqalign{
 g &= 2Rm \cr\cr
dg &= 2\,(R\,dm + dR\,m) \cr
   &= 2\,(R\,dm + Pm\,d\alpha - Qm\,d\beta) \cr
   &= 2\,(R\,dm + Pm\,d\alpha - Qmf\,d\alpha - Qm\alpha\,df) \cr
   &= 2\,(R\,dm + (Pm-fQm)\,d\alpha - \alpha Qmg^T\,dm) \cr
   &= 2\,(R\,dm - Rm\,\frac{d\alpha}{\alpha}- \alpha Qmg^T\,dm) \cr
   &= 2\,(R\,dm - Rm(2\alpha\,m^TQ\,dm) - 2\alpha Qmm^TR\,dm) \cr
 &= 2\,\big(R -2\alpha Rmm^TQ-2\alpha Qmm^TR\big)\,dm \cr
 &= 2\,\big(R -2\alpha RMQ -2\alpha QMR\big)\,dm \cr\cr
\frac{\partial g}{\partial m} &= 2R - 4\alpha(RMQ+QMR) \cr\cr
}$$
So that's the second derivative, but please double-check the algebra before trusting it.

As a quick check, $(Q,M,R)$ are all symmetric matrices, therefore the second derivative is also a symmetric matrix -- as it should be.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post.

Comment: from  $R:2\,{\rm sym}(dm\,m^T) $  to 
         and to $2\,{\rm sym}(R):dm\,m^T $ and to 
         $(R+R^T)m:dm$, Can you give a detailed steps?

Comment: @Johnnylin  I got rid of the sym() operation. Now the derivation utilizes a few basic properties of the Frobenius product $$\eqalign{A:B&=A^T:B^T\cr A:BC&=AC^T:B}$$ which follow from the corresponding properties of the trace.

Comment: I am wondering what the second derivative of g with respect to m is. Can you help ?

Comment: I think here $\eqalign{g&=2m^TR}$ ?